# Ayuda con alternancia estricta dekker - exclusión mutua

Tags: c++

¿Me podrían decir qué puedo cambiar de aquí para que haya alternancia estricta, o sea que bote un hilo a la vez? algo así:

- hilo 1
- hilo 2
- hilo 1
- hilo 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

bool flag[2] = { false, false };

int turn;

void func0() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        flag[0] = true;
        while (flag[1] == true) {
            if (turn != 0) {
                flag[0] = false;

                while (turn == 1) {
                }

                flag[0] = true;
            }
        }
cout << "hilo 1" << endl;
        turn = 1;
        flag[0] = false;
    }
}
void func1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        flag[1] = true;
        while (flag[0] == true) {
            if (turn != 1) {
                flag[1] = false;
                while (turn == 0) {

                }
                flag[1] = true;
            }
        }
cout << "hilo 2" << endl;
        turn = 0;
        flag[1] = false;
    }
}

int main() {
    thread t1(func0);
    thread t2(func1);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como tienes el código no lo conseguirás nunca:

1. No llames a `thread::join`, ya que eso unirá el hilo de ejecución al hilo del programa: es decir, la llamada se volverá síncrona.
2. No uses banderas booleanas, usa `std::mutex`, con uno basta.
3. Debes dar tiempo a un hilo para que tome control del `std::mutex` cuando otro hilo lo libera, añade una espera.

Con [esto](https://tio.run/##jVDLasMwEDx7v2KbHmKTpiSGXmzH557yBQUjZNkW1QtrVQrFv15XtgsNPZRepGGYmd1Z7tyx53ye76XhKrQCKxpGwdoafhgdSLzfEtJ6iiJ9y/FhtMbWAJ7aolgtqEsAEtopRlERjJe9ES1ea3izssUuzeADkuCl6dEwLbxjXOAasMU1SpIYmfIxKOnsiKk0hBIveCrjd3fBcwSHg8wgiUmJflSWv6ZZGfEWYwNhVeHuWSqLuwVel2f/Yvblagjml4UG6ZvtCEXhlRCuiZPTp5P2i2iCCWDZQjNptgLftsWBdE676lxnD0h5RHmdLav/r@Kf83O/Jo2CwmhifZjm@ZN3ivV@PrpN/wU), obtienes el resultado deseado:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex m;

template <unsigned N>
void f()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    {
        m.lock();                          // Bloquear el mutex
        std::cout << "Hilo " << N << '\n'; // Trabajar
        m.unlock();                        // Liberar el mutex
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(50ms); // Esperar tras liberar el mutex
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(f<1>), t2(f<2>);

    // Sin thread::join

    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);

    return 0;
}
```